# Killing a pthread within C without killing the whole process

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a parallel C program running on a shared memory architecture using pthreads.  How do I kill a thread without killing the whole process?  I.e. if one thread finishes first, I want to wait for all the others before exiting.  `exit(status_code)` kills the whole process which is not what I want.  I could have a barrier, wait for all threads to reach the barrier and then exit but there might be an easier way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`pthread_join`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) in the "main" (driver) thread to wait for all the other ones to terminate.

To clarify what "a thread terminates" above means, look at the [`pthread_exit`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html) manpage says:

> Performing a return from the start function of any thread other than the main thread results in an implicit call to pthread_exit(), using the function's return value as the thread's exit status.

So `pthread_join` waits for the joined thread to either return from it start function or call `pthread_exit`.

(You do need to keep track of all the threads you created to use this. And none of these work if you detached the processing threads - you should probably not be doing that in this case anyway.)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `pthread_join()` function to join all of your threads.

As an example, lets say you created 5 threads and you want to contunie your operation from main function when all of the threads are finished.

```
pthread_t threadId[5]; // holder for 5 thread

// Create 5 threads
for(index = 0; index < 5; index++)
    pthread_create(&(threadId[index]), NULL, producer, (void *) &(argsForProducers[index]));

// Join them
for (index = 0; index < 5; index++) 
    pthread_join(threadId[index], NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `pthread_exit()` to end the thread yo are in. If you want to kill a thread from within another thread, you can call `pthread_cancel(threadToKill)`. To synchronize alll threads you can call `pthread_join()`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `join` operation for your application to wait on the threads. Take a look at the [pthread man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pthread/) for a good overview.